# How to use lambda as template argument with default value in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

I want to do a simple thing:

```
void DoUntil(auto predicate = [] { return false; });
```

Obviously this doesn't work - I have to use a template argument:

```
template <typename P>
void DoUntil(P predicate = [] { return false; });
```

But this statement doesn't work either - the Clang gives an error:

> error: no matching function for call to … 
>   note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'P'

If I do call the function without arguments, somehow compiler fails to deduce type from a default argument:

```
int main() { DoUntil(); }
```

I don't want to use `std::function<>` in any way.

Are there any other possible solutions to my problem?

Comment: It's a non-deduced context. Quated from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) non-deduced context, A template parameter used in the parameter type of a function parameter that has a default argument that is being used in the call for which argument deduction is being done.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `std::function`?

Answer (score 12):

Use function overloading instead of the default argument feature. Create a *non-template* function that takes no arguments in addition to the template function:

```
void DoUntil() ;

template <typename P>
void DoUntil(P predicate) ;
```

The no-argument version can simply invoke the template version with the lambda you want to use as the default predicate:

```
void DoUntil() { DoUntil([] { return false; }); }
```

---

The problem with your original approach is that you're trying to provide a default *template* specialization by specifying a default argument value, but without specifying a default *template-type*. Even without involving lambdas, the following won't work because `T` doesn't have a default type, even though `t` has a default value:

```
template <typename T>
void Foo(T t = 3);
```

What's needed is to specify a default type for `T` using `<typename T = int>`.

As noted in WhiZTiM's answer, the default type for the case involving the lambda function must be deduced using `decltype`. This is of course because lambdas have unique types known only to the compiler.

Answer (score 7):

A lambda is an anonymous type with no default constructor (of cause, you can use its copy/move constructor if available). If you must go the lambda way, you can do:

```
namespace detail{ auto predicate = [] { return false; }; }

template <typename P = decltype(detail::predicate)>
void DoUntil(P pred = detail::predicate);
```

---

Rather than trying to fiddle around with *lambdas*. You can go the good old way:

```
namespace detail{
    struct DefaultPredicate{ bool operator()() const { return false; } };
}

template <typename P = detail::DefaultPredicate>
void DoUntil(P predicate = P{});
```

---

Or better still as Kyle Strand [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42207005/1621391).

Comment: If you're going to put a lambda at namespace scope, make it `const` so it becomes implicitly static.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering if providing a default-argument would work if the template-argument were properly defaulted. Excellent.

Comment: Wow! A struct?! No no no... At least think about an `std::function`... Also a simple function (no struct, no lambda) should work just fine. The advantage to the `std::function` is that you can bind other parameters to the final call.